# Javascript add div with class to highlighted text

Tags: javascript

I need to programmatically add some text at the end of a text selection performed by the user. My code works fine except that I am not able to apply the class to the newly inserted element (a div). If I insert the new div to the body (document.body.appendChild(div)), the class applies correctly, so there must be something wrong in the way I add the div to the BOM after the selection. Here the text 'TEXT-TO-APPEND' is added, but not the class.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = ('highlighted');
let text = document.createTextNode('TEXT-TO-APPEND');
div.appendChild(text);

sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
  range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  range.collapse(isBefore);

  var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    node, lastNode;
  while ((node = div.firstChild)) {
    lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
  }
  range.insertNode(frag);
}
```

A complete working example is this

```
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<style>
  .highlighted {
    background: #ccc;
    /*font-size: 18px;*/
    color: red;
  } 
     
</style>
<body>

<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="insertHtmlAtSelectionEnd(' (my text) ', false);" />

<div class="">
 <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
 <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
 <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>

</body>

<script>
function insertHtmlAtSelectionEnd(mytext, isBefore) {
    var text = "";
    var sel, range, node;

    if (window.getSelection) {

            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.className = ('highlighted');
            let textElement = document.createTextNode(mytext);
            div.appendChild(textElement);
                           
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                range.collapse(isBefore);
                
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
                while ( (node = div.firstChild) ) {
                    lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                }
                range.insertNode(frag);
            }

    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you include your markup?  I don't think there is enough here without it to constitute a [mcve].

Comment: i'd use `div.classList.add = "highlighted"`, and would be helpful to see markup.

Comment: I edited my question adding a minimal reproducible example